# Foreach in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prepend a tag to each h2 based on the content that specific h2. Here's what I've tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "h2" ).each(function(){
        var $headingcontent = jQuery('h2').html().toLowerCase();
        jQuery('h2').prepend('<a id="'+ $headingcontent +'"></a>');
    });
});
```

However, this seems to only get the content of the first h2 and prepend it to every h2, it does this multiple times depending on how many h2's are on the page.

What I would like it to do is turn this:

```
<h2>Heading 1</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
```

in to

```
<h2><a id="heading 1"></a>Heading 1</h2>
<h2><a id="heading 2"></a>Heading 2</h2>
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to `.wrapInner()` instead of `.prepend()`? Also, you should probably strip spaces and other characters out of the text...

Comment: No, I specifically want an empty tag added - it's just for navigational purposes :).

Comment: Please also note that spaces are not legal in DOM element ids.

Comment: Thanks for that - guess I can just use a replace to add some dashes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery( "h2" ).each(function(){
    var $headingcontent = jQuery(this).html().toLowerCase();
    jQuery(this).prepend('<a id="'+ $headingcontent +'"></a>');
});
```

Btw, you don't need an additional `a` element at all:

```
jQuery( "h2" ).each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.attr('id', $this.html().toLowerCase());
});
```

Comment: Why would this be a bad idea? potentially slow?

Comment: @user319940: nope, potentially weird. Explain why you need that

Comment: It's being used to make some in page navigation easier for the client, this way they can hotlink to parts in the page just by adding a link to #something and not have to add the anchors themself.

Comment: then may be it's not that weird :-)

Comment: @user319940: btw, you can do what you need without `<a>` at all

Comment: Oh really? I'm open to ideas of how to improve this.

Comment: @user319940: yep, anchor would scroll to any element by its `id`. See my second half of the answer

Comment: Thanks, I've just seen it, looks nice. No major problems with browser support for this method?

Comment: @zerkms not with 'modern' browsers ;)

Comment: @raam8: yep, some w3m users may be not happy with such implementations

Comment: I don't even know how I would look up the browser support for this :/.

Answer (score 2):

I would instead nest the anchor inside the `H2` element.

```
$( "h2" ).each(function(_,el){//Get each element as el and _ as index
    el = $(el); // Cache for performance
    var $headingcontent = el.text().toLowerCase();//Get the text
    //Replace h2 content with the an anchor element with same content;
    el.html('<a id="'+ encodeURIComponent($headingcontent) +'">' 
    + $headingcontent
    + '</a>');
});
```

and ofcourse you don't need I\anchor element at all

```
$( "h2" ).each(function(_,el){//Get each element as el and _ as index
    el = $(el); // Cache for performance
    var $headingcontent = el.text().toLowerCase();/Get the text
   //Add id to element for navigational purposes.
    el.prop('id', encodeURIComponent($headingcontent));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good answer but I don't actually want the headings styled as links. The anchors are just there for navigational purposes :).

Comment: You can style them as specially purposed links, even just a different hover color. It gives sensory input to users.

Comment: This will not link anywhere though, it's the point in which the browser skips to when clicking another link. I think it would be a bad user experience to allow people to click it as it would literally lead no-where.

Comment: @user319940 you can simply add the id to the H2 and still navigate there like #$headingcontent

Answer (score 0):

First i'd make sure it only applies to the H2's you intend, down the line you/someone else may add a h2 somewhere else and get unexpected results...

```
<h2 class='content'>Heading 1</h2>
<h2 class='content'>Heading 2</h2>
```

code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('h2.content').each(function(){
var target = $(this);
        jQuery(target).append($('<a/>',{'id':$(target).text(),text:$(target).text()}));
    });
});
```